# Apache cxf not generating sources in second plugin

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have a problem to generate sources 2 times from same wsdl but with different argument.
In effect, second cxf-codegen-plugin is completely ignored only because its the same url with the first cxf-codegen-plugin.

I tried to regroup them in one cxf-codegen-plugin but this not fixed the problem.

here is my code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>generate-sources-test</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdl>test.wsdl</wsdl>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                    <packagenames>
                         <packageName>com.test</packageName>
                     </packagenames>
                    <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                 </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
         
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
     <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${cxf.version}</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
                <id>generate-sources-testtest</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>test.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb/mapping.xml</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-xjc-Xts</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                            <packagenames>
                                <packagename>com.testtest</packagename>
                            </packagenames>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```